# Regex returning a non-capturing group?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

Okay, so I am new to regex, or at least to actually writing them, but here is what I have:

The string:

```
LDAP://CN=Doe\, John,OU=Users,DC=my,DC=domain
```

The regex (that is not working as expected):

```
(?:LDAP://CN=)([a-zA-Z]+\\?[,\s]?\s?[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Groups matched:

```
LDAP://CN=Doe\, Joe
Doe\, John
```

Captured group:

```
LDAP://CN=Doe\, John
```

What I want to return:

```
Doe, John
```

By my understanding (which is obviously not correct) I was under the impression that if I included `?:` for a captured group it would not return it in the match; and likewise, I do not want to return `\` before the `,` in the middle of the name – which I actually do not know how to exclude a character in a returned result as such. Anyone able to shine some light on the matter?

#

[update]

I was able to get the results being doing the following (I'm using powershell btw):

```
$qryResult = "LDAP://CN=Doe\, John,OU=Users,DC=my,DC=domain"  
[regex]$re = "LDAP://CN=(.*?),OU"  
$result = $re.Match($qryResult)  
(($result.Value -replace "LDAP://CN=","") -replace "\\","") -replace ",OU",""
```

But it would nice to use regex from start to finish replacing the text like so.  It's possible?

Comment: It is impossible to match discontinuous text within one match operation. What tool/language are you using?

Comment: I am driving at the point that you will need to remove the ``\`` after you get a match. Be it the capured value of Group 1 with `LDAP://CN=(.*?),OU=` or your regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using the .Net regex engine which is equivalent to Perl 5 regex

Comment: To answer your other question, you are correct that `?:` indicates a non-capturing group. However, the first match is always the entire matched string (regardless of capture groups). That's why `LDAP://CN=Doe\, Joe` is the first match.

Comment: @BrianStephens  Is there a way to return only the second group matched ~ eg if there were a total of 2, 3 or n groups matched?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am running the regular expression in PowerShell and will not be used for Nintex.  Maybe this could answer the question better?  >>  [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Change your PowerShell to this:

```
$qryResult = "LDAP://CN=Doe\, John,OU=Users,DC=my,DC=domain"  
[regex]$re = "LDAP://CN=(.*?),OU"  
$result = $re.Match($qryResult).Groups[1]
($result.Value -replace "LDAP://CN=","") -replace "\\",""
```

It will target only the second group (your capture group): `.Groups[1]`

Comment: Since I can only check one answer, I'm going to 'check' both with a comment since the answers are perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: OP cannot upvote now. I suggest accepting the answer that works best.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: oh, right - forgot. Then I'll upvote your answer myself, since you were able to reduce it to a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You may get the required results with a single `-replace`:

```
PS> $rx = "LDAP://CN=(\p{L}+)(?:\\?,)?(\s*\p{L}+)?,OU=.*"
PS> $res = $qryResult -replace $rx, '$1$2'
PS> $res
Doe John
```

**Details**:

- `LDAP://CN=` - a literal character sequence
- `(\p{L}+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ letters
- `(?:\\?,)?` - an optional sequence of an optional `\` and a comma
- `(\s*\p{L}+)?`  - an optional Group 2 capturing 0+ whitespaces and 1+ letters
- `,OU=.*` - `,OU=` literal char sequdnce and then any 0+ chars other than a newline symbol.

Comment: Since I can only check one answer, I'm going to 'check' both with a comment since the answers are perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: By accepting an answer, you also let others know the question is dealt with. Please accept the other answer, it was posted first.